# check if a certain character is followed by another character in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have `string format = #,##,0.00,,` and I need to count how many commas there are in it, but in the aforementioned example, the only relevant commas for me are the last two.

I want to check if a comma is followed by `"#"` or `"0"`.

Would a solution like this work?

```
int count = 0
for (int i = format.IndexOf(','); i > -1; i = format.IndexOf(',', i + 1))
{
    // for loop end when i=-1 (',' not found)
       // if next character is # or 0 don't count
       // else count
}
```

Comment: Why are only the last two relevant?

Comment: because the are indicate a power of 1000 that i've to use to scale a certain number

Comment: Didnt you have mistake in question? You write that you want verify if next char is '#' or '0' but in code snippet you have comment points on verification of ',' and '#'. It's bit confusing for me.

Comment: ops.. this is my error

Comment: Is your intention to split that string, and you're trying to ignore the 'empty commas' so your split makes more sense and doesn't end up with empty lines? I'd suggest doing `format.Split(',').Where(item => !String.IsNullorWhiteSpace(item))`. It combines both actions in a rather terse but elegant (I think) solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count commas that are not followed by "#" or "0", regardless where they are located (start, end) of text, you can do this:

```
Regex.Matches("#,##,0.00,,#,##,0.00,,", ",(?![#0])").Count
```

Returns three. Notice that the third comma is not followed by # or 0. If you want the commas to be matched only if they are at the end of the string:

```
Regex.Matches("#,##,0.00,,#,##,0.00,,", ",(?![#0]),*$").Count
```

Returns two.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private int GetCount()
    {
        string format = "#,##,0.00,,";

        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < format.Length; i++)
        {
            //if current char is not ',' skip it
            if (!format[i].Equals(','))
            {
                continue;
            }

            //if current char is ',' and its last in string => count++ because no '#' or '0' folows it
            if ((i + 1) == format.Length)
            {
                count++;
                break;
            }

            //if '0' or '#' folows current char, skip current char
            if (format[i + 1].Equals('#')
                || format[i + 1].Equals('0'))
            {
                continue;
            }
            //next char is not '0' or '#' => count++
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: in the second if you don't check if the character is a ','

Comment: because you already know that, it only pass to second part if current char is ','. I am sure that this solution is working as you want. It's explained in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
  string format = @"#,##,0.00,,";
  string[] arrStr = format.Split(',');
  int count = 0;

  for(int i = 1; i < arrStr.length - 1; i++) 
  {
       string s = arrStr[i];
       //ignore string starting with # or 0 
       if (!s.StartsWith("#") && !s.StartsWith("0")) 
       {
            count++;
       }
   }
```

Here are different inputs and outputs using above code:

```
 //string format = @"#,##,0.00,,";  
 //Commas Count = 2

 //string format = @"a,a,#,0,a,,";  
 //Commas Count = 4

 //string format = @",,";  
 //Commas Count = 2

 //string format = @",";  
 //Commas Count = 1

 //string format = @",#";  
 //Commas Count = 0
```

Comment: Doesn't work. For input=",," returns 3 instead of 2.

Comment: Actually for given input it should return 2

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression. The pattern below addresses only the "last commas" scenario you mentioned.

```
string format = "#,##,0.00,,";

string pattern = @"^#,##,\d\.\d\d(?<LastCommas>,+)$";

var myRegex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);

Match match = myRegex.Match(format);

GroupCollection capturedGroups = match.Groups;

// This will get you the number of commas
int count = capturedGroups["LastCommas"].Value.Length;
```

If the "last commas" are optional (i.e. there can be zero or more), replace `pattern` above with this:

```
string pattern = @"^#,##,\d\.\d\d(?<LastCommas>,*)$";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static int CountDelimiter(string data)
    {
        var count = 0;
        var previous = char.MinValue;
        foreach (var c in data)
        {
            if (previous != '#' && preivous !='0' && c == ',')
                count++;
            previous = c;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

or if you want it in single command style.. you can do that:

```
    public static int CountDelimiter(string data)
    {
        return data.Where((x, xi) => x == ',' && 
        (xi == 0 || (xi > 0 && data[xi - 1] != '0' && data[xi - 1] != '#'))).Count();
    }
```

Comment: i can't understand var previous = char.MinValue. foreach skip the first character in datastring?

Comment: Doesn't work for input=",0,,,0,##,,". Returns 6 instead of 4.

Comment: previous variable is used to 'save' the previous char per iteration. the `var preiouvs = char.MinValue` is just to set an initial value to that varible. (you can set as initial whatever you want there except '#' and everything will still work). there is no skipping - the whole string is being iterated.

Comment: but its not about counting ',' with no '#' or '0' before it. Its about counting ',' with no '#' or '0' AFTER it

Comment: fixed. (didn't notice he wanted # and 0 before)

Answer (score 0):

```
string string1 = "#,##,$,$%%$,0,^^^,,";

char[] a = new char[1]
{
    ','
};

string[] strArray = string1.Split(a);

foreach (string s in strArray)
        {
            if (s.StartsWith("0") || s.StartsWith("#") || s.StartsWith(",") || s == string.Empty)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
```

Here when two commas are there, loop will check for `string.Empty`.

Comment: doesn't doing anything about verifying chars followed after ','

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but its probably this:

```
static int X(string str)
{
    int endPos = str.Length - 1;
    int count = 0;

    for (int pos = 0; pos <= endPos; pos++)
    {
        if (str[pos] == ',')
        {
            if (pos < endPos)
            {
                char next = str[pos + 1];

                if (next == '#' || next == '0')
                {
                    pos++;

                    continue;
                }
            }

            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this, but it does compile:

```
public static int GetModifiedCommaCount(string searchString)
{
    int result = 0;
    int lastIndex = searchString.Length - 1;

    // start looping at our first match to save time
    for (int i = searchString.IndexOf(','); i <= lastIndex && i > 0; i++)
    {
        if (searchString[i] == ',' && (i >= lastIndex || (searchString[i + 1] != '0' && searchString[i + 1] != '#')))
        {
            result++;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: That's what I get for not testing.  It's fixed now, and tested.